# Scanning potentially large file for string in node/electron - cross-platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So, I've got a little electron app that uploads files to site.  In order to track what I've already uploaded, I have a simple txt log file that I append the path to whenever I upload a file.

I have a logging class that is supposed to tell me if a file has already been uploaded.  I've been using [jfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jfile) and it's grep method but it's not working on windows.  On my mac everything is working great.  I'm using path.join wherever applicable, so I dont think it's a slash issues between platforms.  The log file is getting written to just fine as well.

What's an alternative way to check for a string in a potentially large log file?

Comment: what kind of file is that? A literal txt? I believe the job could be better done by using a json file.

Comment: Have a look at a Stream search module, an example https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsearch

Comment: yes, it's a txt file.  I'm doing a simple append to it when I upload a new file.  I thought about json, but then I have to maintain my in memory json and make sure the file gets written out.

Comment: I had tried streamsearch but haven't been able to get it to work

Comment: There are others if you are having difficulty with that particular one. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=stream+search